# Using Virtualbox on Windows 10 Home to run a VHD of my old PCs Windows 7 (recently upgraded from Vista HP) hdd

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualization, vhd, hardware-detection

New Virtualbox user (got Linux mint running smoothly a couple days ago ((new Linux user too)).) Created a VHD of my old PCs hard drive after its psu died (used disk2vhd - didn’t give me the option to prepare it for virtual use.) I tested the VHD in PeaZip and that said everything was fine. So how do I get my Windows 7 VHD to come to terms with its new out-of-body experience? It keeps stalling during boot as it’s looking for its arms and legs and tells me of course that hardware or software may have changed... but I don’t know how to amend the VHD to account for virtualization (phantom hardware syndrome.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment, but extracting any relevant data you wish to keep from the hard drive might be simpler than trying to get it to boot.

Comment: Easier, sure, but I’ve already got all the data. The POINT of doing this is to do it... ars gratia artis.